# How to set permissions for /ttyUSBn and /ttyACMn

Tags: permissions

I want to have a number of ttyUSB devices (e.g. ftdi cables) as well as ttyACM connections default to my user so I don't have to use sudo or go in and change permissions each time.  They all default to root:root.  A friend has 12.04 LTS running in VM on a Mac and his defaults to dialout and the usual method of adding the user to the dialout group works for him.  I've loaded three machines with 12.04 LTS, two of them in last three days and all machines default the USB devices to root:root.

I tried a suggestion that added a file in /etc/udev/rules.d (since deleted) that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/112572/241037

Since the ttyUSB device shows up as the following:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jan 28 09:37 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Add the user to the dialout group with command:

```
sudo adduser _user_ dialout
```

logout, then log back in...