# How to access an usb device in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, usb

I have an USB-device used for measuring currents. When I connect this device to windows, I get a new device in the device manager, and a new COM port I can use for accessing the device. When I connect it to my linux (ubuntu 14.04) it is recognized (I can see it via dmesg). How can I access it there? Is there a similar thing as a COM-port where I can send commands to?
When I do `ls /dev | grep USB`, I get nothing in return. When connecting the device, dmesg tells me:

```
[17480.693973] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[17480.763788] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=104d, idProduct=3005
[17480.763798] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[17480.763805] usb 3-1: Product: CONEX-IOD
[17480.763810] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Newport
[17480.763814] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: A6WXEUPA
```

Therefore I can not access it via /dev/ttyUSBx. Why?

Comment: I had already suggested the solution to access USB device http://askubuntu.com/questions/612355/share-usb-over-network/685825#685825 
Maybe this would help.

Answer (score 0):

It will create a new device, `/dev/ttyUSB0` (or a higher number if that already exists).

You can use that like any other file / pipe, depending on what exactly is connected. You will likely need `sudo` privileges to talk to it, but [see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112568/how-do-i-allow-a-non-default-user-to-use-serial-device-ttyusb0) for the fix.

You can see in `dmesg`, where the device was connected, which port was created.

Comment: That is not working, question is updated.

Comment: Sounds like it's not recognising it or finding a driver. Is this a common device? It appears not, as it doesn't come up in search - is it the data acquisition board (which appears to have limited driver support) from mccdaq? If so, it only claims to have limited Windows support, "Supported Windows® Operating Systems: Windows 7/Vista/XP SP2, 32-bit or 64-bit"

Comment: It is not a common device, but I was hoping that it creates a "COM"-like connection which I can use for sending data to.