# Share USB drive over network

Tags: usb

I'm looking for a free method to share an USB device over network.
I got a RaspberryPi (raspbian) which has an USB device connected. I want to be able to receive and send command to this device from my Linux server.

I tried `remserial` but I'm unable to connect the client to the server.
i also tried `VirtualHere` but it crashed

Do you know some free solution to do it ?

EDIT :

Thx for this tutorial, i tried it but i got some trouble :

```
pi@raspberrypi /boot $ zcat /proc/config.gz |grep USBIP
CONFIG_USBIP_CORE=m
CONFIG_USBIP_VHCI_HCD=m
CONFIG_USBIP_HOST=m
# CONFIG_USBIP_DEBUG is not set
pi@raspberrypi /boot $ sudo modprobe usbip-core
pi@raspberrypi /boot $ sudo modprobe usbip-host
pi@raspberrypi /boot $ sudo usbipd -D

pi@raspberrypi /boot $ usbip list -l
Local USB devices
=================
- busid 1-1 (0424:9514)
     1-1:1.0 -> hub
- busid 1-1.1 (0424:ec00)
     1-1.1:1.0 -> smsc95xx
- busid 1-1.3 (0403:6010)
     1-1.3:1.0 -> unknown
     1-1.3:1.1 -> unknown
- busid 1-1.4 (04f2:1126)
     1-1.4:1.0 -> usbhid
- busid 1-1.5 (04f2:1125)
     1-1.5:1.0 -> usbhid
     1-1.5:1.1 -> usbhid

pi@raspberrypi /boot $ sudo usbip --debug  bind -b 1-1.3
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip.c:134:[run_command]
running command: `bind'
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:162:[unbind_other]
1-1.3:1.0 -> unknown
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:162:[unbind_other]
1-1.3:1.1 -> unknown
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/utils.c:65:[modify_match_busid]
write "add 1-1.3" to /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbip-host/match_busid
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:101:[bind_usbip]
bind driver at 1-1.3:1.0 failed
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:101:[bind_usbip]
bind driver at 1-1.3:1.1 failed
usbip: error: could not bind device to usbip-host
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/utils.c:65:[modify_match_busid]
write "del 1-1.3" to /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbip-host/match_busid
  pi@raspberrypi /boot $ sudo usbip --debug  bind -b 1-1.3:1.1
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip.c:134:[run_command]
  running command: `bind'
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:143:[unbind_other]
  problem getting device attributes: No such file or directory
usbip: error: could not unbind driver from device on busid 1-1.3:1.1
pi@raspberrypi /boot $
```

what could it be ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this software [usbip](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/usbip) and this is how to setup the software and use it on both the server and client side

### Notes:

1. In this tutorial use the `server server1.example.com with IP
   192.168.0.100` and `client client1.example.com with IP 192.168.0.101`, both running Ubuntu These settings might differ for you, so you have to replace them where appropriate.
2. Also The account used in this tutorial is the `root` so if a command is not working either use the `root` or use `sudo` before the command

### Installing And Using USB/IP On The Server

We can install usbip as follows:

```
apt-get install usbip
```

Afterwards we load the usbip kernel modules:

```
modprobe usbip

modprobe usbip_common_mod
```

To check if they really got loaded, run:

```
lsmod | grep usbip
```

The output should be similar to this one:

```
root@server1:~# lsmod | grep usbip
usbip                  15124  0
usbip_common_mod       13605  1 usbip
root@server1:~#
```

To make sure that both modules get loaded automatically whenever you boot the system, you can add them to /etc/modules:

```
vi /etc/modules

[...]
usbip
usbip_common_mod
```

Now we can start the usbip daemon:

```
root@server1:~# usbipd -D
Bind usbip.ko to a usb device to be exportable!
```

Now attach a USB device that you want to export to the server - I'm using a SanDisk USB flash drive here.

Execute the command `lsusb`

to find the corresponding Vendor/Device ID which is in the form of:

```
Bus XXX Device YYY: ID VendorID:DeviceID
```

The output on my server is as follows:

```
root@server1:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5151 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

The Vendor/Device ID of my SanDisk USB flash drive is 0781:5151.

Now run

```
usbip_bind_driver --list
root@server1:~# usbip_bind_driver --list
List USB devices
 - busid 1-1 (0781:5151)
     1-1:1.0 -> usb-storage
```

As you see, the Vendor/Device ID of my SanDisk USB flash drive (0781:5151) corresponds to the BUSID 1-1. We need this `BUSID` to attach the USB device to the server:

```
root@server1:~# usbip_bind_driver --usbip 1-1
** (process:765): DEBUG:  1-1:1.0       -> usb-storage
** (process:765): DEBUG: unbinding interface
** (process:765): DEBUG: write "add 1-1" to /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbip/match_busid
** Message: bind 1-1 to usbip, complete!
```

That's it, we can now use the SanDisk USB flash drive on a remote usbip client.

BTW, if you run...

```
netstat -tap
```

... you should see that the usbip daemon is listening on `port 3240`

so please make sure that this port isn't blocked by your firewall:

```
root@server1:~# netstat -tap
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      537/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:3240                  *:*                     LISTEN      762/usbipd
tcp        0     52 server1.example.com:ssh 192.168.0.199:4024      ESTABLISHED 667/0
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      537/sshd
```

### Installing And Using USB/IP On The Client

We need to install usbip on the client as well:

```
sudo apt-get install usbip
```

Afterwards we load the `vhci-hcd` kernel module:

```
modprobe vhci-hcd
```

To check if it really got loaded, run:

```
root@client1:~# lsmod | grep vhci_hcd
vhci_hcd               19800  0
usbip_common_mod       13605  1 vhci_hcd
```

To make sure that the module gets loaded automatically whenever you boot the system, you can add it to `/etc/modules`:

```
vi /etc/modules

[...]
vhci-hcd
```

Now connect to the usbip server and get a list of available USB devices:

```
    usbip -l 192.168.0.100
(192.168.0.100 is the IP address of the usbip server.)
```

You should find the SanDisk USB flash drive in the output (BUSID 1-1):

```
root@client1:~# usbip -l 192.168.0.100
- 192.168.0.100
     1-1: SanDisk Corp. : Cruzer Micro Flash Drive (0781:5151)
        : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.2/usb1/1-1
        : (Defined at Interface level) (00/00/00)
        :  0 - Mass Storage / SCSI / Bulk (Zip) (08/06/50)
```

To attach that device to the client, run:

```
root@client1:~# usbip -a 192.168.0.100 1-1
8 ports available
port 0 attached
```

Now run `lsusb` and you should find the remote USB device in the output on the client:

```
root@client1:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5151 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro 256/512MB Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

You can now use the remote USB device as if it was a local USB device (e.g. mount it, format it, write to it, read form it, etc.).

### Detaching A Remote USB Device

A remote USB device can be detached as follows:

client1:

Run...

```
usbip --port
```

... to find out the port that the remote USB device uses on the client - in this case it's port 00:

```
root@client1:~# usbip --port
8 ports available

Port 00: <Port in Use> at High Speed(480Mbps)
       SanDisk Corp. : Cruzer Micro 256/512MB Flash Drive (0781:5151)
       1-1 -> usbip://192.168.0.100:3240/1-1  (remote devid 00010002 (bus/dev 001/002))
       1-1:1.0 used by usb-storage
           /sys/class/bsg/1:0:0:0/device
           /sys/class/scsi_device/1:0:0:0/device
           /sys/class/scsi_disk/1:0:0:0/device
           /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/device
           /sys/class/usb_endpoint/usbdev1.4_ep02/device
           /sys/class/usb_endpoint/usbdev1.4_ep81/device
           /sys/block/sdb/device
Port 01: <Port Available>
Port 02: <Port Available>
Port 03: <Port Available>
Port 04: <Port Available>
Port 05: <Port Available>
Port 06: <Port Available>
Port 07: <Port Available>
```

We need the port number to detach the device:

```
usbip -d 00

root@client1:~# usbip -d 00
8 ports available

port 0 detached
```

On the server, we use the `BUSID (1-1)` to bind the USB device to the local system (the --other switch binds the device to the local system so that it is not available over the network anymore):

server1:

```
usbip_bind_driver --other 1-1

root@server1:~# usbip_bind_driver --other 1-1
** (process:7333): DEBUG: write "del 1-1" to /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbip/match_busid
** Message: bind 1-1 to other drivers than usbip, complete!
```

Now go back to the client and check if the remote USB device is still available:

client1:

If all goes well, it shouldn't be listed anymore:

```
root@client1:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

### Links

[http://usbip.sourceforge.net](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/)

[Source of the tutorial (Server Side)](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-usb-over-ip-server-and-client-with-ubuntu-10.04)

[Source of the tutorial (Client Side)](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-usb-over-ip-server-and-client-with-ubuntu-10.04-p2)

Comment: Note for Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) users: you will need a backported kernel from Utopic or newer and fiddle with the binaries. See for more information https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usbip/+bug/898003. Any older supported Ubuntu version unfortunately flawed with bugs and ships with non-working usbip.

Comment: Check this answer before use: http://askubuntu.com/a/647071/187689