# How to make a device have read/write permissins when pluged?

Tags: permissions, tty

I have a home-made device and I wrote a program for data acquisition from it. But each time I plug-in the device I have to change the permissions for `/dev/ttyACM0`, so that the port can be used for data transfer. How can I make this device to have read/write permissions by default. The `lsusb` output for this device is:

`Bus 003 Device 005: ID ffff:0005`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are a member of the `dialout` group you can access serial devices, including `ttySx`, `ttyUSBx`, and `ttyACMx` devices, without changing permissions.

```
$ sudo adduser myusername dialout
```

Alternatively, you could create a udev rule to set the permissions as the device is attached.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/112573/471836

Answer (score 1):

I will add an answer to my own question for anyone that will need this in the future. I followed an answer from @Adam Lussier and have created `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-ttyusb.rules` file with this content (proposed by @Sneetsher):

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="ffff", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0005", MODE="0666"
```

Like this only this specific device is given the read/write permissions. [Reference](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) for anyone wanting to know more about writing rules file.