# How to make a specific device have read/write permissions when pluged?

Tags: permissions, udev, serial-port

I have home made device that can be connected via USB port. When connected it gets ttyACM socket. So I have asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768041/how-to-make-a-device-have-read-write-permissins-when-pluged) some time ago about how to set read/write permissions for device. Following the answer I have created `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-ttyusb.rules` file with this content:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*",MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*",MODE="0666"
```

All works fine! But if I understand correctly, now every device connected on any ttyUSB or ttyACM socket will have read/write permissions. Right?

My question is how can I automatically set read/write permissions only for this device when connected?

Relevant `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID ffff:0005
```

Comment: I used rules for my usb cameras because I needed them to always show up in the same location and sometimes they wouldn't .. i used the following `KERNEL=="video[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTR{name}=="Logitech QuickCam Notebook Pro", SYMLINK+="video-cam1", MODE="0777"` ... you don't seem to have a name but maybe you could use something like `KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*",ATTR{ID}==ffff:0005,MODE="0666"` though you may need the subsystem... This is only a guess from me because I don't fully understand this and has been a long time since I have played with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, it gives permission to public users for all those serial devices.
- You can use `ATTRS{idVendor}` & `ATTRS{idProduct}` to filter out target devices:

  ```
  ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="ffff", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0005", MODE="0666"
  ```

  I add `ACTION=="add"` to skip other unwanted event `remove` (device node removed already) & `change` (device node already added and configured)