# Is there any way to get rid of restrictions?

Tags: permissions

I'm somewhat newbie, so sorry to ask this silly question.
I have recently installed Ubuntu 18. I have two problems with permissions. First of all, Telegram won't open unless you run the sudo command in terminal and it gets the permissions! And the second, after installing Arduino,  I need so much permissions! But i get the error message `Permission denied`; and i have changed the user group to "dialot" but still get the same error!

Please help ...!

Comment: No, your actual problem is in "problem reporting". What's a "small task"? What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe you're right! In the given example, i need read and write access to /dev/ttyusb* but it won't work anyway unless i run the command **sudo arduino** or the other situation **sudo telegram-desktop** ...

Comment: Regarding serial permissions, have a look at [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112568/how-do-i-allow-a-non-default-user-to-use-serial-device-ttyusb0). When it comes to telegram, find out where it stores the user profile, and check the permissions of this.

Comment: hmm ... i used **chmod** and changed and everything is ok about telegram. thanks for the link regarding serials i'm checking it out.

Comment: You shall not run Arduino as root (see last paragraph of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1025755/66509)), you shall not run Telegram as root. It is very likely that you messed your permissions in home folder - revert back them with `sudo chown $USER:$USER -R /home/$USER` and in future use graphical user applications an normal user (without sudo).

Comment: @N0rbert good call :-) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got my answer!
The permissions in my home folder was completely messed up!
I used `sudo chown $USER:$USER -R /home` to reset the settings!
And I used the complete instructions on [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1025755/66509) for Arduino installation and problem regarding serial permissions solved! "umake" did the work!

Special thanks to @N0rbert