# How to read data from a serial port?

Tags: command-line, 22.04, serial-port

In ubuntu 22.04.2 I am trying to read the data coming from a serial port. To find the correct port I do

```
sudo dmesg | grep tty
```

which gives

```
[    0.117304] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    0.793135] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS4 at I/O 0x3060 (irq = 19, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    4.136977] usb 3-6.3.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[27184.158691] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[27190.409672] usb 3-6.3.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

after disconnecting and reconnecting the USB device (around time 28180).
Then according to [this suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22545/how-to-connect-to-a-serial-port-as-simple-as-using-ssh) I do

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

but all I get is

```
[screen is terminating]
```

So how to do it AS SIMPLE AS POSSIBLE without setting up configuration, clicking through menues or navigating on the command line through complex setup stuff? I just want to listen to some information that comes from this serial connection (which is connected to the laptop via USB).

On windows I could use

- hterm
- putty
- MOBA xterm

But what to use on ubuntu?

Comment: If you are still running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS as you state, I'll suggest you apply security fixes & upgrades asap, as a fully upgraded Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system has reported as 22.04.3 for some time now.  You can refer to https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/ which provides the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded week+ before this date.

Comment: There is a Linux version of Putty?

Comment: Is the user that attempted screen apart of the `dialout` group? maybe this will [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112568/how-do-i-allow-a-non-default-user-to-use-serial-device-ttyusb0#comment2469465_112572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `minicom` is in fact what I can use simply. I installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install minicom
```

and then I use

```
sudo dmesg | grep tty
```

to find the correct device, and using

```
sudo minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyUSB0
```

if your device is `/dev/ttyUSB0`. You have to specify the baudrate `-b 115200`, I start it uninitialized `-o` and specify the device to connect to `-D /dev/ttyUSB0`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have screen still installed, double check if the user has the proper group permissions to interact with the serial device. From this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529120/479040) it suggests adding your user to the `dialout` group with `usermod -a -G dialout $USER`. If all else fails, maybe try with `sudo screen` instead.